# Controller executes twice, what is the best solution?

Tags: angularjs

I know where the problem is i just don't know how to go about fixing it. I have two directives that call the same controller and after research i found out its a bad thing and i should use a service or something.

Now i believe i have to communicate between both these controllers. Every time i do a console.log inside the controller it runs twice.

What should i do?

Directives

```
app.directive("sidemenu", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'partials/sidemenu.html',
        scope: true,
        transclude : false,
        controller: 'taskbarController'
    }
});

app.directive("taskbar", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'partials/taskbar.html',
        scope: true,
        transclude : false,
        controller: 'taskbarController'
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
app.controller("taskbarController", ['$scope', 'authData', '$location', 'projectsModal', 'sendMessageModal', 'Poller',
  function ($scope, authData, $location, projectsModal, sendMessageModal, Poller) {

    $scope.inbox = Poller.msgdata;
    $scope.project = Poller.newdata;
    $scope.projects = Poller.projects;
    $scope.messages = Poller.messages;

    console.log($scope.inbox);

    $scope.sendMessage = sendMessageModal.activate;
    $scope.showModal = function() {
        projectsModal.deactivate();
        projectsModal.activate();
    };


    $scope.logout = function () {
        authData.get('logout').then(function (results) {
            authData.toast(results);
            $location.path('login');
        });
    }

    authData.get('session');

    $scope.toggle = function(){
        $scope.checked = !$scope.checked
        projectsModal.deactivate();
        sendMessageModal.deactivate();
    }

}]);
```

Comment: You have add two directives in html which has same controller

Comment: Can you share you HTML code also

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can it be resolved by adding the controller to the page and then just passing some part of your model to an isolate scope on each directive?

Answer (score 1):

You could still use controller (rather then service) as long as you are using it to bind the view (for e.g.) If you want to make a webservice call (for e.g.) then I would use service.

Thing you need to think about is that do you need two directive to share same service or just scope? If they (directive) are functionally different then  use separate service/contr (Single Responsibility Principal) and if they have some shared data/scope then think about how to cater for that.If you want to share scope between controllers then you can use service which gets injects into the controller.

Comment: Quite possible I have to rethink how I have implemented this for an alternative.